# Robots.txt for application

Tags: robots.txt

Is it possible for an application within a website to have its own robots.txt file?

For example, I have a site running under `http://www.example.com` and this has its robots.txt file.

We then have a seperate site running as an application under this domain: `http://www.example.com/website-app`

Is it possible to keep the robots.txt file seperate for the application or do I need to put all the stuff for the application into the main root robots.txt?

Comment: You say it's running as a separate site, that means when you access "/website-app" you'll hit a different website with its own files and then that website can (should) have it's own physical robots.txt file - *however*, from a search engine crawler perspective, that site is not a different site, and it's a part of www.test.com, so it will see www.test.com as the same site as www.test.com/website-app, so I would recommend the robots.txt files are similar in content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `robots.txt` file needs to reside in `/robots.txt`, there is no way to tell the crawler that it can be found anywhere else (like for favicons for example). So if you can you should add this to your root `robots.txt` (or put your application on a subdomain instead where it can have its own file).

If you want to control specific pages individually you can use `<meta>`-tags instead, as described at [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html). Since this needs to be put on every page it will have the crawler visit (but not index) at least one page, but it won't follow to other pages (unless you tell it to). For a small application in a subdirectory this might be an ok solution.